# How to convert String Date MM/DD/YYYY to IsoDateTime Format to fetch the Date from MongoDB which is in the mongoDB database

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, jpa, java-8

```
  String fromDate = requestObject.get("fromDate");
  String toDate = requestObject.get("toDate");


  SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX");

  Date fromDateCalculated = simpleDateFormat.parse(fromDate);
  Date toDateCalculated = simpleDateFormat.parse(toDate);
```

i tried this but it did not worked its giving me parceExcpetion

my input string date is like MM/DD/YYYY format

```
{    
    "fromDate":"12/28/2022";
    "toDate":"12/28/2023";  
}
```

however to retreive the date from mongoDB its in format of

e.g. this : `1991-01-29T11:01:43.577+00:00`

or u can say `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX`

Comment: If I understand your question correctly you are trying to parse the date `12/28/2022` (taken from your `fromDate`) using format `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX`. Your input date does not match the format. That won't work and you will get a Parse exception. It looks more like you should use format `MM/dd/yyyy` for parsing that input. 
Also on a significant side note. Do not use SimpleDateFormat. It has been superseeded long ago. Use classes in the java.time.* package instead.

Comment: basically you need two *formatters*, one for parsing, a second for formatting (if you really need input and output as `String`) As already commented, it is better to **not** use the old `SimpleDateTime`, `Date`, and related classes - better use the classes from the `java.time` package (these also use ISO8601 as standard format, so you can avoid the 2nd formatter)

Answer (score 0):

> *"How to convert String Date MM/DD/YYYY to IsoDateTime Format to fetch the Date from MongoDB which is in the mongoDB database ...*
>
> *... in format of*
>
> *e.g. this : `1991-01-29T11:01:43.577+00:00` ..."*

The *[DateTimeFormatter](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html)* class provides *[predefined formats](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#predefined)*, this specifically is available via the *[DateTimeFormatter#ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME)* field.

You'll need to parse the values with the *[LocalDate#parse](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDate.html#parse(java.lang.CharSequence,java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter))* method.
Additionally, apply a *[ZoneOffset](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/time/ZoneOffset.html)* value.

```java
String fromDate = "12/28/2022";
String toDate = "12/28/2023";
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME;
DateTimeFormatter f1 = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MM/dd/yyyy");
LocalDateTime fromDateCalculated = LocalDate.parse(fromDate, f1).atStartOfDay();
LocalDateTime toDateCalculated = LocalDate.parse(toDate, f1).atStartOfDay();
OffsetDateTime x = fromDateCalculated.atOffset(ZoneOffset.UTC);
OffsetDateTime y = toDateCalculated.atOffset(ZoneOffset.UTC);
System.out.println("x = " + f.format(x));
System.out.println("y = " + f.format(y));
```

Output

```
x = 2022-12-28T00:00:00Z
y = 2023-12-28T00:00:00Z
```